# To remove characters from a string after last dot(.)

Tags: sql, oracle

Can anyone tell me how to remove characters from a string after a particular character, in my case DOT(.)

I have a string:

```
1110.400000.8001382
```

I need a SELECT query to remove all the characters after the **last** DOT(`.`)

Expected output is:

```
1110.400000
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What's the expected result if there's no dot at all? Do you want the complete string, or an empty string/Null? https://dbfiddle.uk/4QcgOsaK

Comment: I think this column will have the dot all the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can try a regex replacement here:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('1110.400000.8001382', '\.[^.]*$', '') AS output  -- 1110.400000
FROM dual;
```

### Demo

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `SUBSTR` and `INSTR` functions to remove all characters after the last dot.

```
SELECT SUBSTR('1110.400000.8001382', 1, INSTR('1110.400000.8001382', '.', -1) - 1)
AS output FROM dual;
```

The `SUBSTR` function is used to extract the substring from the beginning of the string to the last dot. The `INSTR` function is used to find the position of the last dot in the string. The `-1` argument in the INSTR function tells it to search for the last occurrence of the dot.

The function will now output the desired result.